# In Firebug, $ == jQuery returns false, only sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

Okay, I have this weird problem in Firefox.  I type in Firebug's console

```
$ == jQuery
```

Sometime it displays true, and sometimes false.  The file is just an empty HTML document with one script tag including jQuery.  I refresh the page, click "Run" in the console, and again, occasionally it returns true, occasionally false.

On the occasions where it returns false, `$.toString()` gives

```
function anonymous() {
    return window.console.notifyFirebug(arguments, "$", "firebugExecuteCommand");
}
```

Now here's the weird thing.  When `$ == jQuery` gives false using Firebug's console, if I go to the address bar and type `javascript:alert($ == jQuery);`, it alerts true!

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?  It's (occasionally) messing up my debugging.

Comment: It looks like Firebug uses the $ symbol for something.  Just a thought -- not sure if that's valid or not.

Comment: It could be `noconflict` or something. If you try doing `$===jQuery` without jQuery actually loaded you'll get a reference error in addition to `false`

Comment: Firebug's command line binds `$` to [a function that calls `getElementById`](http://fbug.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/content/firebug/commandLineAPI.js). I can't think of a very good practical reason that there'd be a mixup between the two though, unless you're somehow running the snippet before the jQuery script fully loads (but this seems unlikely to me).

Comment: @Nick, which version of Firebug are you using?

Comment: @CMS, Firebug 1.6X.0b1 and Firefox 3.6.8

Comment: There is a general obsession with `$`. Even Chrome defines it as a shortcut to `getElementById`.

Comment: I always type `var $ = jQuery;` on the console before anything else :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a native function defined by firebug that assigns `$` to getElementById. I don't think you can resolve this "bug" without upgrading to a newer version of Firebug which potentially eliminated the issue, or manually assign `$ = jQuery`.

It's probably come as a result of possibly jQuery already being cached and the Firebug `$` overriding it as it fires too fast, or vice versa.. just some weird bug in regards to speed of assignment + caching.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe firebug is using $ for something and there´s a race condition between jquery and firebug for setting that variable, you have to consider that a lot of javascript libraries use that variable name, if I´m not wrong prototype is one of them

Answer (score 0):

You should be using instanceof instead of an equality check.

For the reason why it us likely that firebug have defined $ in a local scope.

Answer (score 0):

There could be many other things using $ as a function/variable symbol. jQuery is just one of them. Firebug is probably overriding $.